# Allow duplicate products in woo commerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, js-fancyproductdesigner

Does anybody know how to set up product variations using Fancy Product Designer?

I.e. Different color t-shirts of the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up Product Variations.

EG You may have a T-Shirt that comes in various sizes. The TShirt is the product, however the variations are Large Medium Small. They cann all hold the same SKU or you can modify the SKU for each variant

More info here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/

Comment: The question is how to allow the same product being added twice, because dynamic customizations are being made, aside from variations.  I am using http://fancyproductdesigner.com/woocommerce-plugin/

Comment: I still probably do not understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. When you say you want to add the same product twice are you meaning the same SKU. What are the differences between adding sameproduct 1 and sameproduct 2? How are customisations currently being stored in the backend?

You could set a custom field for each type of alteration and store what alteration has occurred in this area.

I also have a webstore that sells the same product but the customer creates their own custom alterations and this is how we do it

Answer (score 1):

I had this with a tshirt company site that I was creating. What I had to do was give each item an individual stock number (SKU) for each design despite it being the same tshirt.

Hope this helps,

Ben.

Comment: Problem is were using Fancy Product Designer, and the user can make for each product (adding multiple designs, or designs of their own)

Comment: Ah, ok then sorry I can not help  - best of luck.